# Movement between Images in Gallery with Next & Prev Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have how many images in gallery that when click on the any image,image displayed on the other bigger img tag.i would like to implement a previous and next button that i could movement between images.i think could use next() method in javascript and i found below Example but i'm beginner in js and i could not dose this work.

```
<script>
var interval = undefined;
$(document).ready(function () {
    interval = setInterval(getNext, 2000); // milliseconds
    $('#next').on('click', getNext);
    $('#prev').on('click', getPrev);

    $('.slideshow a').onclick(function () {
       var src=$('a img').attr("src");
       $('#bigImage img').attr("src",src);
    });
});

function getNext() {
    var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible'),
        $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('.slideshow img').first();

    transition($curr, $next);
}

function getPrev() {
    var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible'),
    $next = ($curr.prev().length) ? $curr.prev() : $('.slideshow img').last();
    transition($curr, $next);
}

function transition($curr, $next) {
    clearInterval(interval);

    $next.css('z-index', 2).fadeIn('slow', function () {
        $curr.hide().css('z-index', 0);
        $next.css('z-index', 1);
    });
}
</script>

<div class="slideshow">
    <a href="#"><img src="first-image.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="first image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="second-image.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="second image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="third-image.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="third image"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="fourth-image.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="fourth image"></a>
    ...
</div>
<button type="button" Id="prev">Previous</button>
<button type="button" Id="next">Next</button>
<div id="bigImage">
    <img src="#" width="800" height="600" alt="Big Image">
</div>

<style>
.slideshow {
    position: relative; /* necessary to absolutely position the images inside */
    width: 500px; /* same as the images inside */
    height: 100px;
}
.slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.slideshow img:first-child {
    display: block; /* overrides the previous style */
}
</style>
```

Please Guide Me!
thanks!

Comment: You have no added element for Next & Prev.
It should have ids next &  prev for Next and Prev element respectively.

Comment: Oh!i forgotted ,has Added.